# Table-responsive-sm class doesn't work

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

this table responsive class works on every device but the only problem is when I open up my website in iPhone, whole table doesn't get the table-dark class background. I attached the screen shot for the table, see when I scroll the table to the right to see the overflowed part of the table, it doesn't have the black background.

[image: Table scrolled supposed to be with black background and white color but it is getting default values not like the rest of the table.]

```
<div class="table-responsive-sm">

  <table class="table table-dark table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>.</th>
      <th>Wix.com</th>
      <th>Sqarespace.com</th>
      <th>Weebly.com</th>
      <th>GoDaddy.com</th>
      <th>21webDexter</th>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Working fine for me. Can you please reproduce it in a fiddle

Comment: Yeee... it works for me too can you show your code please

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xkcrj91d/#&togetherjs=Ouq11qzzdL

Comment: It works for me too...but when you open up the website in mobile phone, table-responsive class adds a scrollbar and when you scroll the table to see the rest content, that part of table doesn't get the background color dark like table-dark class. So if you see image, the black background is table content before scrolling and when you scroll, the rest of content does not have the black background but it has green body background. Here is my website if you wanna open up website in mobile phone and locate and scroll the table to see my problem.  http://21webdexter.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: I think it has only problem with iPhone, it works totally fine with android OS.